# PHP code inside MYSQL table does not show

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to convert a drupal installation into a front end driven by Code Igniter. This is an experimental project to check the performance boost I can get. But the biggest problem I am facing is that few fields in Drupal store php string as it is. For example

```
<?php print "A"; ?>

This is normal
```

Now I am able to see the text "This is normal" which comes from the query that I run in Code Igniter, but I don't see the php function which is saved inside the table. I can see the text when I view the record through phpmyadmin. But somehow not inside the CI query result.

Comment: Can you post your query and a var_dump() of it result? Maybe it's just me but I didn't understand what the exact problem is.

Comment: sound like it's because the php doesn't get processed on output or a strip_tags is being used on the string. see if html tags output to verify.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_type] => node
            [bundle] => article
            [deleted] => 0
            [entity_id] => 38
            [revision_id] => 38
            [language] => und
            [delta] => 0
            [body_value] => 
            [body_summary] => 
            [body_format] => php_code
        )

) This is the var dump or rather print_r and the mysql table does contain the string <?php print "a"; ?>;

Comment: Try to use http://php.net/manual/fr/function.eval.php

Comment: Hi sdespont I could have tried that.. but the problem is I am not even getting the string from MySQL. The field is a long text field. I see the php code when I view the data through phpmyadmin. But when the query result is coming through codeigniter the string is not visible. Not sure if CI is doing something in the back end.

Comment: Hi guys... can someone please help me out on this. I am still not able to get a solution to this. :(

Answer (score 1):

I hope U've got the solution. But just in case if you haven't try this:

I created a table with two columns

[image: Table Content]

```
//$result Contains the data fetched from the table using a model.
foreach ($result as $key=>$val) {
   if($key == 'code') {
      $val = str_replace('<?php','',$val); //Remove PHP's opening tag.
      $val = str_replace('?>','',$val); //Remove PHP's closing tag.
      $val = rtrim($val); //Remove leading and trailing spaces.
      echo $key.': ';
      eval($val.';'); //Execute the PHP code using eval.
    } else {
       echo $key.': '.$val.PHP_EOL;
    }
 }
```

I tried

1. `echo $result['code']`
2. `print_r($result)`
3. `var_dump($result)`
4. `highlight_string($result['code'])`
5. `eval($result['code'])`
6. and finally `str_replace` followed by `eval($result['code'])`.

Check the screen shot of the result obtained from: [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fb1p.png)

There you can see that the Result produced by 1,2, and 5 are empty. But when you inspect element against the empty space It'll clearly show that the string that's echoed/print is commented out.

[**Screen-Shot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxm8E.png).

This is has nothing to do with codeigniter. Its done by **HTML Parser**.
So the solution is to remove the opening and closing tags of PHP and then use eval. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Yes, the last resort was the eval function and that is the one which helped me attain which I was wanting it to do.

The data which was inside the database had PHP function and only eval function was able to treat that part as a PHP code and execute it when I was getting the data inside my view.